# Unpredictable Access-Control-Allow-Origin behavior

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome

I have a Rails app with the following action:

```
def some_action

  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://www.example.com'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'GET'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

  n = Model.getNumber
  render :json => {:count => n}
end
```

I have some jQuery on example.com that does a `$.getJSON` on that action.  Strangely, the behavior is completely unpredictable.  Running those GET requests every few seconds, about 50% of them fail with the dreaded "Origin http://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" message.

I really would have expected it to either work 100% of the time or fail 100% of the time.  Why would it behave differently across multiple requests, seconds apart from the same browser?

Edit:  I am caching that action... not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are the headers the same for failing and succeeding requests?

Comment: The request headers are... the response headers are not.

Comment: It sounds like an caching issue to me. If you are using an HTML cache it might be dropping the headers or if you are caching the data in your code make sure the headers get added regardless.

Comment: Post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like an caching issue to me. If you are using an HTML cache it might be dropping the headers or if you are caching the data in your code make sure the headers get added regardless.

Comment: Removing the action caching fixed the problem.